# Bootstrap textarea adding extra spaces in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am making a simple contact form and was trying to add a bootstrap textarea, but it is showing some weird behaviour whenever I click on the textarea it creates whitespace after the div in which the form is, and also it loses the default property of the bootstrap textarea i.e rounded border. But this is not the case in Chrome it works fine on chrome.

Any help will be appreciated, please tell me if anything wrong i am doing.
Here is the page where the issue is:

https://www.reviewzpanda.in/about.php

Comment: Can't replicate, works fine in chrome and firefox.

Comment: @Second2None Why its not working on my side ?

Comment: Firefox might need updating.